# Export displacement texture from displace modifier

Tags: export

I used a displace modifier and created a texture for it. How do I export that texture? Thanks.

Comment: @BlenderMaster15, so you should write this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1__olo3hds Hope this helps!